# Align Div to bottom of page, absolute positioning does not work

Tags: html, css

I want to put a `DIV` in bottom of page in two different situation, if content of page has enough height to fill the screen bottom `DIV` should stick to the end of `content` `DIV`, and when it has not enough height or it's empty, in this situation bottom `DIV` should stick to the end of page.

It's my HTML and CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/eWhvs/embedded/result/)

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#FFF;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://ashraafi.com/img/bgpattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#wrapper{
    min-width:900px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:relative;
}
#top{
    width:inherit;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:relative;
}
#content{
    width:inherit;
    background-color:#36C;
    position:relative;
}
#bottom{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;   
   left:0;
   background-color:#42210b;
   width: inherit;
   height: 35px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
        top
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        content
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
        <p>foo</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        bottom
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you have `position:relative` on the `#wrapper`. If you remove it then the positioning will be relative to the page.

But to get a sticky footer is a little more complex than that. I would recommend: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: It seems it works, thank you, I'll mark it as answer if it keep working.